# How to Print decimal 0 as 000 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, number-formatting

i am converting hex data to decimal and the range is from 00 to FF

```
 hex_data = "FF"
int("0x" + hex_data , 16)
```

returns
    255
but when i give 0 as hexdata it gives 0 wheras i need it as 000

how to do it

Comment: integers wont show with extra digits on front, try strings

Comment: Please tell me reason for marking negative

Comment: `int()` returns an int, so it cannot return `000` because it's the same number as `0`. You have to stringify it this way or another

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to format it:

```
hex_data = "FF"
number = int("0x" + hex_data, 16) 
print '%03d' % number # either this
print '{:03d}'.format(number) # or this (Python >= 2.6)
```

Comment: @DSM: Would be better suited as a comment on the question though.

Answer (score 1):

And for completeness sake, you could also do:

```
str(int(hex_data, 16)).zfill(3)
```